# Como inserir date e datetime em uma tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data

[image: Erro na inserção de dados do tipo date e datetime]

O grande problema é que após o `insert`, todos os valores que tem data, ficam como **zeros** e no formato `yyyy-dd-mm` e não `dd/mm/yyyy`, como foi inserido inicialmente. Como eu posso inserir estes valores na formatação que eu desejo?

Comment: SQL, mysql? sql server? a data deve ser gravada como `yyyy-mm-dd` no select vc utilize alguma função que o banco fornece para formatar conforme necessario.

Comment: Sim, seu banco o formato é `yyyy-mm-dd` a configuração e você não respeito isso, então, ele colocou zeros, to achando que é Mysql tal comportamente, mas, seria legal colocar a linguagem (se tiver usando) e o nome do banco.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei o que uso, MySQL.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Você não pode inserir diretamente dados em qualquer formato que deseje no MySQL para campos *datetime* e *timestamp*. O formato que o MySQL utiliza é o padrão ISO: `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` e algumas [variantes na mesma ordem](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Entretanto, isto não impede o usuário de converter os formatos no momento da entrada e saída dos dados - lembrando que de qualquer forma, o formato de armazenamento vai se manter igual no DB.

Veja como fazer esta conversão utilizando as próprias funções do MySQL:

### Para visualizar datas como `dd/mm/aaaa` no `SELECT`:

Com a função `DATE_FORMAT( data, formato )` você pode converter uma data em uma string formatada.

Exemplo para sua tabela:

```sql
SELECT usr_idusuario, DATE_FORMAT( evn_dtevento, "%d/%m/%Y" ) AS data_evento FROM evn_evento;
```

### Como utilizar uma string `dd/mm/aaaa` ao se fazer o `INSERT`:

A função que faz o inverso do exemplo acima é `STR_TO_DATE( string, formato )`.

Aplicando à sua tabela:

```sql
INSERT INTO usr_idusuario SET evn_dtevento = STR_TO_DATE( "31/05/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" ), ...
```

### Como utilizar uma string `dd/mm/aaaa` na cláusula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE dia = STR_TO_DATE( "31/05/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" );
```

Ou para um intervalo:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela
WHERE  dia BETWEEN
           STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" ) AND
           STR_TO_DATE( "31/10/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" ) ;
```

### *Placeholders* dos formatos mais comuns para nosso *locale*:

```
%d   Dia (00..31)
%e   Dia (0..31)
%m   Mês (00..12)
%y   Ano (dois dígitos)
%Y   Ano (quatro dígitos)
%%   Caractere %
%H   Horas (00..23)
%i   Minutos (00..59)
%s   Segundos (00..59)
%T   Hora completa ( 24 horas, formato hh:mm:ss)
```

Os formatos estão listados na íntegra no [manual do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) <sup>(en)</sup>

Comment: Em uma cláusula `WHERE` devo usar `DATE_FORMAT` ou `STR_TO_DATE`?

Comment: @Patrick depende do tipo do campo e do que você quer fazer. Eu normalmente trabalho sempre com a data no formato original do MySQL, então não uso função nenhuma. Só controlo na aplicação a exibição na tela.

Answer (score 0):

O Formato padrão é `YYYY-MM-DD`, para extrair a informação deverá ser tratado na aplicação ou na consulta.

Criando o campo com valor padrão no banco, ou passando `now()` no `INSERT`.

Assim será completado com o valor atual.

Comment: Usar o `now()` só resolve o problema quando a data é a atual. Se for uma data retroativa ou futura, por exemplo, esta não seria uma opção viável. Talvez seja interessante dar mais contexto e explicar quais são outras alternativas e/ou como lidar com o formato de data sugerido pelo autor da pergunta, caso tenha algo mais a acrescentar ou melhorar além da resposta aceita. ;)