# Como salvar data no Mysql utilizando prepared statments

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou trocando os campos pra guardar data no MySQL, de`varchar` pra `date`, e fiquei em dúvida sobre a forma correta de incluir os campos de data  no banco usando `prepared statments`.

Como uso DD/MM/YYYY durante o script pra fazer algumas comparações etc,  queria fazer a mudança só na hora de incluir no banco, durante o `insert`.

Acho que não dá pra usar o `STR_TO_DATE( string, formato )` com `prepared statments`, como indicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17697/23400), então, seguindo esta [`outra resposta`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49858/23400) adaptei assim:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql)) {

mysqli_stmt_bind_param
(
    $stmt,
    's',
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataDMY)),
...
```

E deu certo, mas debugando recebo um notice `undefined variable`, que não aparecia sem colocar `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataDMY))` dentro da execução do `bind::param`. Desta forma está correto? Qual a forma ideal?

Comment: de onde vem `$dataDMY` ?

Comment: De um campo do formulário. Ele vem no formato dd/mm/yyyy...

Comment: mas onde essa variável está definida no php? Deve ter algo do tipo `$dataDMY = $_POST['dataDMY']`.. algo por aí

Comment: Ah, então, tá em outro arquivo, este arquivo é apenas para incluir no bd, e incluo com `include` no final do arquivo de saída do form... então quando roda ele acha a variável, mas debugando dá este notice que não dava antes...

Comment: Faz assim, antes desse trecho `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql)) {`, coloque isso `print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); exit;` E coloque o resultado na sua pergunta.

Comment: Então, a saída pra este campo com o `print_r` é por exemplo: `[dataDMY]=> 11/10/2010`... Amanhã edito a pergunta, porque agora o sono bateu mesmo :) valeu por enquanto! Abraços!

Comment: A ideia é vc receber a variável no formato `d/m/Y` e converter para `Y-m-d` e ai gravar no banco.

Comment: isso @rray, é isso mesmo...

Comment: Q bom resolveu o problema, sobre o `undefined variable` o código que ocorre isso não está na pergunta. o [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) parece aceitar só referências como argumento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato vindo no POST é `string`. É preciso converter para uma instância de data.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['dataDMY'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Assim a variável estará pronta para ser inserida no banco em um campo do tipo `TIMESTAMP` ou `DATETIME`.

Comment: Valeu Junior, mas tenho ainda uma dúvida: não daria pra fazer essa conversão dentro do `bind_param`, da forma como coloquei na pergunta `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataDMY))`. Porque isso ia garantir que a conversão ocorresse apenas pra incluir no banco, já que ela é usada em vários outros arquivos no formato dd/mm/YYY... também daria pra converter logo antes do `bind_param`, mas queria saber se tem algum "mal" em converter dentro do bind_param... valeu por enquanto. +1

Comment: Não existe nada de errado nessa forma de fazer dentro do bind. Eu fiquei pouco confuso com essa sua questão. Não teve muito nexo

Comment: É, acho que ficou meio confusa mesmo, mas mesmo assim você ajudou bastante. :) Valeu.