# Dúvida sobre o erro "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in"

Tags: php, mysqli

Para gravar algumas datas no banco de dados no formato desejado estou fazendo assim:

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param
    (
        $stmt,
        's',
        date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data))
    );
```

Ou, para pegar o dia atual, simplesmente:

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param
    (
        $stmt,
        's',
        date("Y-m-d")
    );
```

No entanto, apesar de gravar normalmente, recebo este erro (*notice* né?):

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in line "5" // é na linha da data...

Está errada esta forma de passar o valor para o campo? Qual a correta? O que significa este erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim está errado, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` espera que o segundo(OO) ou o terceiro(procedural) argumento seja **sempre** uma referencia isso significa que deve ser uma variável e não o retorno de uma função/método ou valor passado direito.

O correto é criar uma variável antes de chamar `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` ou fazer a pesquisa por data pelo banco de dados usando a função `now()` ou equivalente.

```
$data = date("Y-m-d");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $data);
```

Comment: Ah, entendi, valeu!

Comment: @gustavox, isso não deveria nem funcionar é so isso que tem na linha do erro?

Comment: Só isso mesmo...

Comment: [Esta minha pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89352/como-salvar-data-no-mysql-utilizando-prepared-statments) é relacionada, dá uma nos comentários da resposta aceita (cuja solução eu não segui hehehe)...

Comment: @gustavox, testei aqui deu certo(inseriu) com um retorno de função(que não deveria) já com um valor passado direto ele não fez o insert. Vou ver depois pq esse comportamento funciona, A ideia é só passar variáveis mesmo :P.

Comment: hehe, vou corrigir aqui :-) valeu!

Comment: @gustavox, tem uns artigos [aqui](http://phpdelusions.net/safemysql) sobre o mysqi/pdo e uma classe melhorada para fazer consultas foi [esse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) usuário do SOen que fez, vale apena dar uma olhada.