# Como fazer um select entre datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A minha pergunta é bem simples, pretendo fazer um `SELECT` entre datas, de uma determinada tabela, onde o `status='1'`.

Ou seja, tenho por exemplo:

```
$data1 = 13/01/2017
$data2 = 20/01/2017
```

Quero fazer um select de todos os resultados entre estas datas onde o status=1

Como poderei fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar vários filtros em `WHERE`, basta colocar `AND` entre eles.

Para um intervalo entre duas datas, utilize `BETWEEN`.

Lembre-se que as datas precisam estar entre aspas e no formato yyyy-mm-dd.

Exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABELA
WHERE 
    status='1'
    and data between '2017-01-13' and '2017-01-20';
```

Nota, isso se seu campo do banco de dados estiver definido como DATE.

Se estiver no DATETIME, tem que usar '00:00:00' para a primeira data '23:59:59' para a segunda.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABELA
WHERE 
    status='1'
    and data between '2017-01-13 00:00:00' and '2017-01-20 23:59:59';
```

Se estiver no formato DATETIME e não quiser se preocupar em colocar o horário (sugestão de @Bacco):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABELA
WHERE 
    status='1'
    and DATE( data ) between '2017-01-13' and '2017-01-20';
```

Se estiver no formato TIMESTAMP, pode usar UNIX_TIMESTAMP, conforme sugerido por @Inkeliz.

Comment: @Bacco, poderia me ajudar em uma questão? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177343/31016 Pelo menos me indicar um caminho... se der para falar no chat me avisa. Ou manda msg no comentário.

Comment: Deixei uma dica lá, tou de saída, mas se deixar um teste no codepen ajuda a gente tentar algo. Mesmo que eu não consiga ver isso hoje, algum colega pode ver o link e o comentário com a dica, e tentar te ajudar. Eu acho que essa de fazer o evento de tecla separado do chosen vai ajudar. Aí no IF você ve se a tecla é del, e se o elemento é o do chosen. Se nao for deixa o evento quieto pro browser fazer o que faria normalmente. se for, chama o método que vc quer. Ai nem mexe no fonte do Chosen.

Comment: Eu experimentei o chosen rapidamente aqui, e o delete apaga labels, mas nos campos com texto pra digitar o delete funciona normalmente para eliminar seleção. Se puder, depois deixe um comentário aqui ou lá depois explicando o que dá errado quando você tenta deletar. Testei no FF 50.1.0 no Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Depende do formato que está no seu banco de dados.

**Se estiver no formato `DATETIME`:**

Use `DATE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Status = 1 AND DATE(Data) > '2017-01-01' AND DATE(Data) < '2017-01-17'
```

Use `00:00:00`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Status = 1 AND Data > '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND Data < '2017-01-17 00:00:00'
```

**Se estiver no formato `DATE`:**

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Status = 1 AND Data > '2017-01-01' AND Data < '2017-01-17'
```

**Se estiver no formato `TIMESTAMP/INT`**:

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Status = 1 AND Data > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND Data < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-17')
```

Comment: No caso de date, o formato da data está y-m-d?

Comment: Exato, este é o padrão do MySQL.

Comment: Data é yyyy-mm-dd. Qualquer coisa diferente disso, nao é data no DB. Se precisar converter para armazenar corretamente, tem isso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17679/70 - que é uma das maneiras mais simples para manter correto no DB mas mostrar e gravar formatado em dd mm aaaa;

Comment: Vou experimentar, aqui no meu projeto, assim que terminar valido a resposta.