# Como guardar a data numa tabela em mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou  a tentar inserir a data atual numa tabela, estou a usar o seguinte código:

```
insert into testar (data,nome) VALUES (date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'pedro');
```

porem da erro:

> Column 'data' cannot be null.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como inserir date e datetime em uma tabela no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17679/como-inserir-date-e-datetime-em-uma-tabela-no-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Faça uso de `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
INSERT INTO testar (data,nome) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'pedro')
```

Comment: Funcionou obrigado.

Comment: @Rui aproveita e leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o **NOW()** para colocar a data atual.

```
INSERT INTO testar 
(data, nome)
VALUES 
(NOW(), 'Pedro')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o comando NOW() para isso ficaria assim:

```
insert into testar (data,nome) VALUES (NOW(),'pedro');
```